# problema con longitud de listas

Tags: python, lista

Tengo un problema, quiero que dado una lista, si la longitud de todos sus elementos es de 2 retornar true, y sino retornar false
pensé en hacer algo cómo esto:

```
def longitudes(lista):
    for elem in lista:
        if len(elem)==2:
            return True
    else:
        return False

print(longitudes(["22","22","232"]))
```

el tema es que claro, el for recorre la lista y ve si la longitud de uno de los elementos es igual a 2 y me retorna true, yo quiero que me retorne true solo si la longitud de todos los elementos es igual a 2

Comment: Una forma complementaria con [all()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all): `return all([len(x)==2 for x in lista])`. Devolverá `True` o `False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para saber si **todos** los elementos cumplen la condición, usarás `and` con una expresión como:

```
R = E1 and E2 and ... and En
```

También conocida como producto lógico. Ya que se comporta de forma similar producto aritmético:

```
R = E1 * E2 * ... * En
```

Si al menos uno de todos los operandos es 0 (o `False`), no hace falta seguir evaluando la expresión para saber que el resultado es 0.

Pongamos un ejemplo:

```
R =  1 *  1 *  0  *  1 =  0
// True True False True False
```

De manera similar, si quieres saber si al menos uno de los elementos cumple la cocción, usarás un `or`:

```
R = E1 or E2 or ... or En
```

También conocido como suma lógica por su similitud a la suma aritmética:

```
R = E1 + E2 + ... + En
```

Y puedes ver que con un solo elemento que sea 1 (o `True`) no hace falta que sigas evaluando para saber que el resultado es 1.

Pongamos un ejemplo:

```
R =  1 +  1 +  0  +  1 =  1
// True True False True True
```

Ahora debería serte evidente que tu código falla porque realizaste el algoritmo de una suma lógica en lugar de un producto lógico. Ya que al primer elemento que cumpla la condición devuelve `True`.

De ahí que la corrección sea evaluar la condición opuesta e invertir los valores de retorno:

```
def longitudes(lista):
    for elem in lista:
        if len(elem)!=2:
            return False
    return True
```

---

Para que resulte menos confuso, también puedes hacerlo así:

```
def longitudes(lista, longitud):
    iguales = True
    for elem in lista:
        iguales = iguales and len(elem) == longitud

    return iguales

print(longitudes(["22","22","232"], 2))
```

Nota que `iguales` se inicia en `True` ya que es el elemento neutro del producto lógico.

---

Si te resulta difícil entender la respuesta, sugiero que leas algún libro o veas algún video sobre álgebra booleana para adquirir los conceptos básicos.

O si te interesa profundizar en lógica también te lo recomiendo ya que encontrarás teoremas interesantes que puedes aplicar. Una herramienta muy útil es el [Mapa de Karnaugh](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapa_de_Karnaugh), ya que te permite simplificar una expresión lógica.

Comment: `all()` es una función básico de Python.

Comment: @CandidMoe si vi que lo habían dicho en los comentarios de la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

El retorno dentro del for solo debe ir si el largo es distinto de 2. Esto es porque al primero que encuentre ya es falso. Luego el True va fuera del for, porque si no encontró ninguno distinto a 2, es que es true

```
def longitudes(lista):
    for elem in lista:
        if len(elem)!=2:
            return False
    return True

print(longitudes(["22","22","232"])) #False
print(longitudes(["22","22","11"])) #True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def revisar(lista):
    return all(len(x) == 2 for x in lista)
```

El `for x in lista` recorre todos los elementos calculando `len(x) == 2`, lo que resulta en una lista de puros `True` si se cumple la condición. Si hay un elemento de largo distinto a dos, tendremos un `False`.

La función `all()` retorna `True` si todos la secuencia es `True`.

Comment: Seria un generador en este caso. Y all de hecho acepta cualquier iterable. No solo secuencias. Sin embargo, esta me parece la respuesta mas pythonica de entre las tres.